# How to make multiple calls to class methods in the same line?

Tags: php, class

I have an issue in PHP.
In my php file, i created the following line:

```
$foo = $wke->template->notify()
                     ->type("ERROR")
                     ->errno("0x14")
                     ->msg("You are not logged.")
                     ->page("login.tpl");
```

In the end, I need my `$foo` variable will return this:

```
$foo->type = "ERROR" 
$foo->errno= "0x14" 
$foo->msg= "You are not logged." 
$foo->page= "login.tpl"
```

Please note that the `$wke->template` is where i need call the `notify()` element.

Comment: The question is not clear. Explain your original intentions just by words

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it in one line ? you should do it in separate calls!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need create a method to build a variable with all informations i need. I need to be customize all method called to do specific things and, in the same time, return all informations i need.

Comment: You'll have to return the object itself with every call, and store the arguments in properties of the object I guess. Chaining is not a default behaviour, your object methods have to be prepared for it. (or otherwise, if you are just getting started, just call each method separately)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The way of calling function of class one by one just by "->" because the function returning the same object of the class. See the example below. You will get this

```
class Wke {

    public $type;
    public $errno;
    public $msg;
    public $page;

    public $template = $this;

    public function notify(){
        return $this;
    }

    public function errorno($error){
        $this->errno = $error;
        return $this; // returning same object so you can call the another function in sequence by just ->
    }
    public function type($type){
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }
    public function msg($msg){
        $this->msg = $msg;
        return $this;
    }
    public function page($page){
        $this->page = $page;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The whole magic is of `return $this;`

Answer (score 1):

Each of those methods will need to return some object that stores what you set as the argument in it. Presumably, it will be the `template` that contains each object property on it, and when you call the method it sets that corresponding variable and returns itself.