# What are these for: $this->foo()->bar(); and why do you use them and how can you use them?

Tags: php

I have seen these in scripts before but have tried looking on google, but can't seem to find anything on them, albeit I bet they're easy to find if you know their names.

What are they for? Are they to join two methods?

```
$this->foo()->bar();
```

How do you make them? A small simple class answer along with the description would be cool

Why would you make them? A simple use would be cool

I have seen frameworks use them for forms like:

```
Form::input('name','input', array())->outside('morestuff')
```

Links and details would be great.

Comment: Does this answer all your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11553055/3933332 ?

Comment: It's called a "Fluent interface" or "Method Chaining" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650010/method-chaining/28650111#28650111

Comment: TLDR version: each of the methods has `return $this`, basically.

Comment: jQuery does this in JavaScript, Propel (an ORM) does this in PHP, and Spiderling (a test framework) also does this in PHP. There are probably loads of examples. It's quite nice because often, you can set up your IDE to autocomplete on each `->` reference, which saves you having to remember the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) with functions/methods on them.  They're simply constructed in such a way that they resemble a "fluent" API.  When you look at this line:

```
$this->foo()->bar();
```

You're looking at *two* objects.  (Which may or may not coincidentally be of the same type, or even the same instance, depending on how the object is designed.)  The first object is:

```
$this
```

That object has a function on it called `foo`, which you can invoke:

```
$this->foo()
```

This function *returns* an object, and *that* object has a function called `bar`, which can also be invoked:

```
$this->foo()->bar()
```

Sometimes for clarity you might want to extract an explaining variable, which is functionally equivalent:

```
$anotherObj = $this->foo();
$anotherObj->bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for convenience only, it is a matter of coding style. Suppose that you want to call two methods over a object, then in standard style you would write something like:

```
$this->foo();
$this->bar();
```

If you prefer to write it in a single instruction then you can make `foo` returning `$this` and this will let you write `$this->foo()->bar()`. Of course, you can imagine that `foo` returns some other object on which `bar` can be called.

In the second case there is nothing special, a function `Form::input` returns an object on which you call a method.

Answer (score 0):

A php class can return itself by using the statement `return $this;` this allow you to make method chaining.

```
class MyClass{

    public function foo(){
         // ...
         return $this; // Return itself
    }

    public function bar(){
         // ...
         return $this; // Return itself
    }

    public function test(){
         $this->foo()->bar(); 
         //....
    }
}
```

Outside the class this :

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->foo()->bar();
```

Would be exactly the same as this

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->foo();
$myClass->bar();
```